# Receiving TypeError: undefined is not a function (near'...posts.map...') React-Native / Rails 6.0 API

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to run my Expo App on the iPhone/Android devices, but I receive

> "undefined is not a function (near'...posts.map...')"

But the application runs on iOS emulator...It does show the error on the Android emulator. I'm fairly new to React Native and I'm trying to figure out **why it's not returning the objects for my iPhone (physical) and Android Emulator**.

The full error is below and the code that I wrote will follow it. **How can I fix this TypeError issue and correctly display the results on my iPhone/Android Emulator?**

Full Error:

```sh
TypeError: undefined is not a function
(near'...posts.map')

    This error is located at:
     in Home (created by
     Context.Consumer)
     in Route (at App.js:21)
     in Switch (at App.js.30)
     in RCTSafeAreaView (at SafeAreaView.js:55)
     in SafeAreaView (at App.js:19)
     in App (at App.js:35)
     in Router (created by Memory Router)
    ....
```

My React Native Code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios'
import {ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import PhotoPost from '../components/PhotoPost';
import ErrorBoundary from 'react-native-error-boundary'

const Home = () => {
 const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

 useEffect( () => {
  Axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/image_post/index')
  .then(res => {
    setPosts(res.data)
  }).catch(e => setPosts(e.message))
}, []);

 return (
  <ScrollView>
    <ErrorBoundary>
      {posts.map((posts, index) => {
        return(
          <PhotoPost key={index} post={post} />
        )
      })}
    </ErrorBoundary>
  </ScrollView>
 )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: check res.data is an array or not

Comment: It's returning an object in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You should use (post, index) instead of (posts, index) since you use variable post in the component PhotoPost.

```js
<ErrorBoundary>
  {posts.map((post, index) => {
    return(
      <PhotoPost key={index} post={post} />
    )
  })}
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `map` in JS, data must be an array.

Inside `catch` you are directly assigning error message to `posts` as `setPosts(e.message)` & try to use map. That's why `undefined is not a function (near'...posts.map...')` occurred because at that time `posts` is not an array.

There are multiple ways to fix this error but it is better to keep a separate state to handle errors as below,

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import { View, Text, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import PhotoPost from "../components/PhotoPost";

const Home = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/image_post/index")
      .then(res => {
        setPosts(res.data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        setError(true);
        // log error
        console.log(e);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {error ? (
        <View>
          <Text>Error while loading data </Text>
        </View>
      ) : (
        posts.map((post, index) => {
          return <PhotoPost key={index} post={post} />;
        })
      )}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.